# Route to data-populated page on login with Angular2 and Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Right now I have an Angular 2 project that takes a users' login credentials, and re-routes the user to my profile component.

**home.component.ts**

```
constructor(public router: Router){}
  signInSubmit(){
    var self = this;
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(self.signInForm.value.smail, self.signInForm.value.spassword).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error.message);
    });
    self.router.navigate(['profile']);
  }
```

where `profile` represents a page with a users' Firebase data (such as their username). My problem is that the user data is not populated by the time the user is redirected. They have to refresh the page to see it populate.

My **profile.component.ts**

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
private addsnotes$: FirebaseListObservable<string[]>;
private username$: FirebaseObjectObservable<string>;
addForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private af: AngularFire){}

ngOnInit(){
   let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
   let userNamePath = `users/${user.uid}/username`;
   let notesPath = `users/${user.uid}/addnote`;

   this.username$ = this.af.database.object(userNamePath);
   this.addsnotes$ = this.af.database.list(notesPath);
} 
}
```

my **profile.component.html**

```
<h4>Welcome {{ (username$ | async)?.$value }}</h4>
```

When I am redirected to my Profile route, I am told that `user` is null. But again, this is not a problem if I simply refresh the page. How might I retrieve and output the user's data on the re-route? I am also willing to consider a page refresh option, though I am unsure how to refresh to a separate route in Angular 2.

Comment: What happens when you use a `setTimeout` function on the `user` data

Comment: After setting a timeout on everything inside my ngOnInit, it still returns an error once they are initiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are redirecting immediately after attempting to sign in with your credentials. You need to wait for the sign in to be successful before you want to reroute.

The `signInWithEmailAndPassword` is a **Promise** based call that also returns the user info after a successful call. So you can do this:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(
  self.signInForm.value.smail,
  self.signInForm.value.spassword
)
  .then((userInfo) => {
    // Login was successful, NOW redirect
    self.router.navigate([ 'profile' ]);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Do something, such as report the error on your sign in page
  });
```